# Advertisement image doesn't load from https page

Tags: bug, https

Visiting [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677649/should-a-cantor-diagonal-argument-on-a-list-of-all-rationals-always-produce-an-i) I see this advertisement in the right-side sidebar:

[image: "404 invalid referrer"]

I'm not sure if this is because I'm visiting from a page with an https URL or if it's something caused by the [https-everywhere extension](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/) I recently installed.

I am using `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0`.

I understand that SE is still working on support for HTTPS and that the support is so far incomplete.  This is a bug report, not a request for help.

**ADDED** 2014-02-24: The URL of the broken image is, as predicted below by user 127.0.9.6, is  http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/bounty.png

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature! :-P

Answer (score 6):

Sorry about this. By design, browsers will not send the referer when coming from an HTTPS site to a non-HTTPS site, which breaks the ad.

To counteract this, I've added a route where you can specify the site manually. This should work for all users:

http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/math.stackexchange.com/bounty.png

I've edited your Community Promotion Ads post with the new URL, hopefully you shouldn't have any more issues.

Comment: It still won't work for HTTPS users who've disabled mixed content on secure pages, though. You might be able to simply use a [protocol-relative URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just); they work in most places, assuming that the server responds to both HTTP and HTTPS requests (and yours seems to). I've never tried them in community ads before, but I suspect they'd work.

Comment: ...yep, [it's working](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/12008/4). Just saw the ad in rotation, loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Good to know, thanks for testing that

Answer (score 5):

Https is not supported yet, SE is working on it but currently a lot of stuff is still broken. You should disable HTTPS Everywhere for SE as you'll run into a few other problems as well, e.g. Mathjax not working.

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date: [MathJax is now supported over HTTPS](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12447/127096).